# Spring SecurityConfig unit test for ignoring Web Security on particular URLS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have a SecurityConfig class with the following method we over ride from **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(ignorePatterns);
}
```

The ignore patterns we use are for URL's we don't want any authentication to apply to (we use Bearer tokens) i'm trying to write a unit test for this to ensure the behavior behaves as expected

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Test {
       
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAuthenticationAtWhiteListedURL() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/v3/api-docs")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer: foo"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAuthenticationAtNonWhiteListedURL() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/needs-authentication")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer: foo"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But both tests are returning okay which is not expected, anyone ever tested something like this before and whats best approach?

Comment: What URLs are you ignoring in ignorePatterns?

Comment: things like swagger-ui URLS and URLS for spring actuators

Comment: Did you try accessing URLs via browser? Are they accessible?

Comment: Yes they are so config works. But I want a unit test for it